# How I remove last word from my every line with AWK or CUT

Tags: text-processing, awk, cut

```
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files (x86)/BigFix Enterprise/BES Client/__GTS/jre/bin/java.exe
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe
ACRBAMIDKC125,/Program Files/Tivoli/TSM/baclient/jvm80535/jre/bin/java.exe
```

And expected output we want

```
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files (x86)/BigFix Enterprise/BES Client/__GTS/jre/bin
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin
ACRBAMIDKC125,/Program Files/Tivoli/TSM/baclient/jvm80535/jre/bin
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show what you have tried this far, and why you think it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563060/how-to-cut-the-last-field-from-a-shell-string

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed 's,/[^/]*$,,' file
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files (x86)/BigFix Enterprise/BES Client/__GTS/jre/bin
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin
ACRBAMIDKC125,/Program Files/Tivoli/TSM/baclient/jvm80535/jre/bin
```

This uses `sed` to remove everything after the last `/` character on every line.

The regular expression `/[^/]*$` matches a slash followed by any number of non-slash characters at the end of the line, and the substitution removes these (replaces them with nothing).

The same thing in `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub("/[^/]*$", ""); print }' file
```

The `cut` utility would be awkward to use here as you have no fixed delimiter to cut at. You could obviously *reverse* each line with `rev` and extract from the `/` onwards, and then reverse again, but this seems a bit too much work when both `sed` and `awk` can do the same work much more cleanly.

```
$ rev file | cut -d '/' -f 2- | rev
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files (x86)/BigFix Enterprise/BES Client/__GTS/jre/bin
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin
ACRBAMIDKC125,/Program Files/Tivoli/TSM/baclient/jvm80535/jre/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with something like:

```
awk -F\/ 'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {$NF=""} 1' input_file
```

or you can use this to avoid trailing slash (work with GNU `awk`, may not work with other versions)

```
awk -F\/ 'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {NF-=1} 1'  input_file
```

Comment: This may work with GNU `awk`, but there's generally no guarantee that decreasing `NF` will remove fields from the current record.

Comment: @Kusalananda, this was just crazy idea to try. In next days will be able to test it on Solaris and will report the result :)

Comment: I've checked with OpenBSD `awk`, GNU `awk` and `mawk`, and it seems to work. However, nowhere in [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does it say `NF` may be assigned to, or what the consequence of that may be.  GNU `awk` and `mawk` appears to document this as an allowed behaviour, so you may want to specify that you're using one of these `awk` implementations.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Solaris 11 x86  `awk` do not like `BEGIN`, have no variables, do not work at all. `nawk` (same platform) do not work with `NF-=1`

Comment: FWIW the POSIX standard defines what happens when you assign NF to a larger number than it had or increment it (you get empty fields tacked on the end of the record), it just doesn't define what happens when you decrement it so it's hit-or-miss when you do that. The default awk on Solaris that I think you're refering to is old, broken awk and should simply never be used. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or xpg6) as it's much closer to POSIX compliance than nawk.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you, will check it :)

Comment: @EdMorton, `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` work fine with `$NF=""` but `NF-=1` have no effect (NF do not change value)

Comment: Rights, that's what I'd have expected. The same would be true for the awk on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

command

```
awk -F "/" 'OFS="/"{$NF="";print $0}' filename| sed "s/\/$//g"
```

output

```
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files (x86)/BigFix Enterprise/BES Client/__GTS/jre/bin
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin
ACRBAMIDKC125,/Program Files/Tivoli/TSM/baclient/jvm80535/jre/bin
```

Comment: This is 99% the same as [Romeo Ninov's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561181/117549) with the addition of the `sed` command at the end of yours. Why is that sed command there? It appears to be stripping a trailing slash, none of which exists in the input.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: setting `$NF=""` produces a trailing / (as Romeo's A actually says) which OP doesn't want. Although you could avoid the separate sed with `{$NF=""; sub("/$",""); print}` or even `{$NF=""; print substr($0,1,length-1)}`

Answer (score 0):

Done in python method

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
y=re.compile(r'/[a-z]*\.[a-z]*$')
k=open('i.txt','r')
for i in k:
    print re.sub(y,"",i).strip()
```

output

```
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files (x86)/BigFix Enterprise/BES Client/__GTS/jre/bin
ACRBAMIDKC124,/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin
ACRBAMIDKC125,/Program Files/Tivoli/TSM/baclient/jvm80535/jre/bin
```